# Defining reduced arity partial functions

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I've sometimes found it convenient in Clojure to define reduced arity versions of functions, that return a partial function, e.g.

```
(defn prefix 
  ([pre string] 
    (str pre ":" string))

  ([pre] 
    (fn [string]
      (prefix pre string))))
```

This means that you can do either:

```
(prefix "foo" 78979)
=> "foo:78979"

((prefix "foo") 78979)
=> "foo:78979"
```

This seems quite Haskell-ish and avoids the need for `partial` to create partial functions.

But is it considered good coding style / API design in Lisp?

Comment: This is currying, yes? Seems useful. And I think the interface here could be improved. It would be nice if you could make this technique generic; that is, for functions with all keywords, if you call that function with an incomplete set of keywords, it returns a closure that accepts all keywords remaining. If all keywords are consumed, then you get the function's value. I could see this being used as an optimization technique.

Comment: I think it is still ideomatic if you name you partials for readability when you define them like so: (def prefix (partial ...)) So this has both: A name to refer and it is explicit. Note that you don't use defn now but def- partial is creating the function for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In languages where functions are curried by default, the function calls are also curried. When one writes
`(f a b c)`, the language interprets this as `(((f a) b) c)`. This is not the case in Clojure.

I believe that making curried functions in an environment where calls are not curried by default creates a conceptual mismatch - this construct will probably cause confusion in readers (I mean human readers of your code.)

If your function has more than 2 arguments, the definition gets ugly quickly. Suppose a function has 4 arguments. To fully emulate the currying call, you need to handle cases like `((f a b) c d)` when someone first passes 2 arguments and then the remaining two. In this case the overloaded version of the two-argument function needs to return an overloaded function that behaves differently depending on whether it gets 1 or 2 arguments. I guess it's possible to automate that with macros, but still.

Also, you kill the possibility of defining default arguments and the `& rest` construct.

Comment: default arguments and variadic `&rest` functions

Comment: @6502 Yes. Edited for completeness.

Answer (score 9):

Using `partial` to create a curried function is based on the concept of **Explicit is better** (in most cases :)). And I have found that this concept to be more applicable/used in dynamically typed languages like Clojure, Python etc may be because of the missing type signature/static-typing it makes more sense to make things explicit .

Answer (score 6):

hmmm... personally, I'd rather see `partial`, since that makes it clear what's going on.

I don't know if it's "good" or "bad" coding style, but I've never seen this style before in existing Clojure code and I can imagine that people using an API would expect both `(prefix "foo" 78979)` and `(prefix "foo")` to return the same kind of object.

To make the difference between both functions clear you could do something like this instead:

```
(defn prefix [pre string]
  (str pre ":" string))

(defn prefix-fn [pre]
  (fn [string]
    (prefix pre string)))

(prefix "foo" 78979)      ; => "foo:78979"
((prefix-fn "foo") 78979) ; => "foo:78979"
```

Comment: "I've never seen this style before in existing Clojure code"---it's all over Hickey's new reducers library.